# Singular matrix in nodal analysis?

Tags: circuit-analysis, math

I'm currently learning about nodal analysis from a set of lecture notes. The notes are rather brief, and one question which occurred to me is whether it is possible for the admittance matrix to be singular.

That is, can we imagine a circuit that's physically possibly but whose admittance matrix is singular, so that we cannot determine the node potentials using nodal analysis?

It seems plausible that the answer would be in the negative, but I would like to see a formal argument. Note that I am not talking about issues with the admittance matrix being *nearly singular*, which might be problematic for numerical solution methods.

Comment: An old question touching on this one (but asking for intuition to explain the math instead of vice versa): [Intuition behind why nodal and mesh analysis work?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/104907/6334)

Comment: For a more mathematical explanation, see [this](http://eestaff.kku.ac.th/~jamebond/182304/Loop%20Cutset.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

If you connect two nodes with a short circuit, then other things permitting you can still solve the nodal equations.

If you connect two nodes with *two* short circuits, then in the physical world it's not possible to determine how much current flows in each. If you set up the admittance matrix for this situation, it will be singular.

A similar situation exists if you put two open circuits in series and try to solve for the mid point voltage.

This is quite a common error in SPICE analysis, where it's all too easy to  have a floating node between two capacitors, or the parallel connection of two ideal inductors. A judiciously placed very large or very small resistor is needed to bring the singular matrix back to computability.

Comment: Thanks! From a practical point of view, that's very helpful. However, I would still like to see a more mathematical argument. Also, I'm not quite sure I understand your argument with the short circuit. If two nodes are connect by a short circuit, they must have the same potential. Then it wouldn't matter if we added another short circuit, right? If we introduce two node potentials for these nodes, the admittance matrix would not be defined, since it would contain infinite entries.

Comment: @ÉtienneBézout If we add a further short circuit to two nodes already short-circuited, but treat them both as a single s/c, then yes, it's all fine, and we can solve the rest of the circuit, as long as we represent both shorts by a single short and only want the total current between those nodes. If we try to add another row/column into the matrix to distinguish the current in the two shorts, *then* we have duplicate columns, which singularises (is there such a word?) the matrix. Is proof any more than 'N unknowns, N equations, result, happiness, N-1 equations, result, misery'? (Micawber)

Comment: Well, one could in principle have N unkowns, N equations and still misery. An NxN matrix can be noninvertible (singular); that's basically my question. I should clarify that what I mean is this: Introduce relevant node potentials and apply KCL to relate said potentials. This means we do not directly consider short circuits since we would get infinite admittance. We get a linear system of equations. In matrix form, this is G*v=y, where v are the potentials, y is due to sources and G is the admittance matrix. Is G always invertible?

Comment: @ÉtienneBézout yes, N, N-1, that was incomplete of me. When trying to resolve the extra current through the other short circuit, or the voltage of that floating node, we find ourselves writing an equation that's identical to a previous one, so duplicating a column, so rendering the matrix singular. Of the N columns in the matrix, we only have N-1 *independent* columns.

Comment: Ok, I get your point. But let's just focus initially on node potentials. Then it doesn't make sense to consider two nodes connected by one or more short-circuits as separate. Once we have found the node potentials, we could find the current through the short circuit if there's only one, as you said. But if we neglect any short-circuits, i.e. for determining node potentials we consider short-circuited nodes as a single node, could we have a singular matrix?

Comment: @ÉtienneBézout if you use human intelligence to reduce shorted nodes to a single node, or multiple shorts to a single short, and construct the matrix from the reduced problem, then you won't get a singular matrix. If however you 'play dumb computer', and systematically number the nodes, number the branches, construct the matrix, like SPICE does, then it can be singular.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit reluctant to accept your answer, since I was looking for a more mathematical argument. "The photon" provided me with a link that I'll look into. Regardless, I appreciate your answer and comments.

Comment: @ÉtienneBézout Yes, I don't really do proofs, sorry, engineer rather than mathematician. Once I've established to myself that it's possible to create both singular and non-singular from a similar circuit, and the only difference is floating nodes or loops of shorts, then I get bored. The mechanism leaps out at one, the duplication of columns due to the degeneracy in the circuit. I do like exploring the difference between the way a human approaches a problem, and a dumb systematic algorithm, our unconscious pre-processing of what's 'obvious' is quite non-obvious! Photon's link, looks plausible.